# Creating a Swarm cluster with Virtualbox nodes on OSX, the connection is unavailable

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a cluster, first I create the nodes

```
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox node1
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox node2
```

Then I connect to the first node and start the swarm mode with the public ip

```
$ docker-machine ssh node1
$ docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.0.2.15
```

The second command gives me the command to join the swarm

Then I connect to the node2

```
$ docker-machine ssh node2
```

And I run the command to join the swarm

```
$ docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-377ttnr1dn42ukidq5bmk7d7yzxuccawy4w7dokdv2ho80v743-5g35bgosj9hnixuclcvrarzlb 10.0.2.15:2377
```

But I get the following error

> Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable

-- UPDATE 1

I was using the public ip addresses (eth0), and it has the behaviour I described. However, if I use the private network (eth1) it works. Not sure why, I will try to discover the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `docker swarm` in virtual box is not really recommended as it has a lot of bugs and consider the possibility of services not being able to communicate on services located on other host.

Comment: thank you for your answer, let me ask, which would be a suitable setup if I want to try swarm on my local environment.

Comment: I really would just recommend you to do it in Digital Ocean if you are just practicing. Digital Ocean has a $5 per server minimum. If you have a rasperry pi or other servers on your place that you can use a substitute, it should also work well but just not on virtualbox